# Preparestatement gives an error with this statement

Tags: c++, mysql, prepared-statement

Currently in my code I have something like this

```
std::string SQL = "SELECT SObject   FROM `EEng`.`orders` where  nStatus not in (?,?,?) and  Quantity!=? and Category=? and freq=? and lev=? and price=?";
```

I get the following error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x75d0c41f (KernelBase.dll) in EEng.exe:
Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x048cf1f4..
```

When I attempt to do this

```cpp
prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement(SQL);
```

any suggetsions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Are question mark parameters allowed in this dialect of SQL? (Yes, they are if this is MySQL as indicated by the tag.) (If not, you may need _named parameters_ instead.) And if they are, have you set the parameters before submitting the query?

Comment: Hey @Rajeshwar, have you found the problem? I have exactly the same issue.